# How to get matched dataset column value?

Tags: c#

like below I want to get dataset column value by another column name? so how to do that?

```
string areaName = dsArea.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"].ToString();
dsCustReg.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows["areaName"](ds.Tables[0].Rows["AreaId"]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do there? That doesnt make sense. What do you expect to get from `.Rows["areaName"](ds.Tables[0].Rows["AreaId"])`. A `DataRow` has an indexer which takes an int not a string.

Comment: thats what I want..I want areaId value which is in 'ds' by matching 'AreaName' that is also have in 'ds'.

Comment: What is matching what? Still not clear, sorry. Maybe an example would help. Do you want to update a single DataRow or all rows? You want to update the field `AreaName` with the field `AreaId` of another row in the same `DataTable`? How do you find this row? Is it possible that multiple rows are matrching? What should happen in that case, should i use the first?

Comment: if (dsArea.Tables[0].Columns["AreaName"].ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Columns["AreaName"].ToString())
                        {

Comment: for that iam matching like above

Comment: `table.Columns["ColumnName"]` returns a `DataColumn` not a value of one of the rows in the table. And `DataColumn.ToString` returns the name of the column which is `AreaName` in your case. You're confusing things. You still haven't edited your question to provide a meaningful sample.

Comment: if u can tell in your way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get name from database and there you put condition in where clause then bind that name into dataset or any then compare it your requirement table column.

Comment: then it will not much load on server?because i have to do like this on four to five tables.